# R function creating and changing

Tags: r, function

I have code that works:

```
#  V(c)(c, E, HS, EC_50) has the form of a 3-parameter log-logistic dose-response function

# EC_50 is the log-transformed EC50 dose,
# HS is the Hill slope or slope factor,
# E is the lower asymptotic response limit,
# c is the log-transformed dose.
# v(c) drug concentration


V_C <- function(c, E, HS, EC_50) E + (1 - E) / (1 + exp(HS * (c - EC_50)))


# define some (sensible) values for the  parameters
c <-  seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1)
HS <- 1
log_EC50 <- log(1e-3)
E <- 0
```

I want to change my code so that my function calculated the mean and that I could give V_C (drug concentration) as a parameter, e.g. 10, 100, 250 in the function. My output should be mean for my V_C function for the parameter values I gave.

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: my  output shuld be  mean

Comment: the mean of what?

Comment: Sorry for answering just now, but I didn't have internet access. Mean for my V_C function for the parameter values I gave

Comment: Once again, sorry for the delay reply and please help

Comment: Thank you user438383 for editing my post.

Comment: I'm still not following. Can you give an example? What exactly do you want the inputs and outputs to be?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question input parameters values for example 
(I can give any values)  c <- 2 HS <- 1 log_EC50 <- 2 E <- 0  V_C <-100 output mean

Comment: Again, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a little confused by the question. if you just want the mean of `V_C` then you can just use `mean`:

```r
V_C_mean <- function(c, E, HS, EC_50) mean(E + (1 - E) / (1 + exp(HS * (c - EC_50))))

C <-  seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1)
HS <- 1
log_EC50 <- log(1e-3)
E <- 0

V_C_mean(C, E, HS, log_EC50)
#> [1] 0.4253818
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer AndS. Can I modify my function so that V_C is also a parameter and not a result?

Comment: To clarify my question Can I modify my function so that V_C is also a parameter and not a result?

Comment: This is an important question for me. Can I modify my function so that V_C is also a parameter and not as result?

Comment: what would be the result?